# mvc3 how can i return a repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, repository

I have recently foundout the benefits of using repositories and I am very new at it my question is how can I now return the code? For instance in my regular controller before I used a repository I return the code like this

```
public ActionResult Index(int? zips, double? rad)
    {


        if (!zips.HasValue)
        {

            string connectme = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["looglercontext"].ConnectionString;
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectme))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                var articles = sqlConnection.Query<Article>("Select top 20 * from articles").ToList();
                return View(new homepage { article = articles });
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

now I am putting that code inside a repository and since they don't take ViewModels to return I am basically lost this is what I have

```
public homepage FirstRepository(int? zips, double? rad)
  {
      if (!zips.HasValue)
      {

          string connectme = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["looglercontext"].ConnectionString;
          using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectme))
          {
              sqlConnection.Open();
              var articles = sqlConnection.Query<Article>("Select top 20 * from articles").ToList();
              return  new homepage { article = articles};
          }
      }
```

// How can I return something here if null for repository
}

**I get the error not all code path returns a value**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this code to compile you could return an empty list in the case your `if` condition is not satisfied:

```
public IList<Article> FirstRepository(int? zips, double? rad)
{
    if (!zips.HasValue)
    {
        string connectme = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["looglercontext"].ConnectionString;
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectme))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            var articles = sqlConnection.Query<Article>("Select top 20 * from articles").ToList();
            return articles;
        }
    }

    return new List<Article>();
}
```

and then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? zips, double? rad)
{
    var articles = someRepo.FindRepository(zips, rad);
    return View(new homepage { articles = articles });
}
```